# LinkedIn not updating link preview Open Graph data

Tags: linkedin-api, facebook-opengraph

I'm trying to post a link to LinkedIn. Once the link is typed/pasted, a preview appears. This preview is supposed to draw properties such as the thumbnail image, title, description, and URL from Open Graph tags. If it cannot find such tags, it uses the rest of the page to figure it out.

[Here is LinkedIn's documentation page on this specific matter.](https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/answer/46687/making-your-website-shareable-on-linkedin?lang=en)

It says to use the following tags:

```
<meta property='og:title' content='Title of the article"/>
<meta property='og:image' content='//media.example.com/ 1234567.jpg"/>
<meta property='og:description' content='Description that will show in the preview"/>
<meta property='og:url' content='//www.example.com/URL of the article" />
```

I've done exactly that, and while Facebook is able to see all of the data that I've specified, LinkedIn is somehow having trouble.

I've tried all of the tricks:

- Appending a fake parameter to the URL to trick LinkedIn into thinking the link is new
- Validating the entire page in the W3C validator and fixing any errors
- Adding `prefix="go: http://ogp.me/ns#"` in the meta tags
- Logging in and out of the LinkedIn Account
- Using the non-HTTPS version of the link

Since unlike with Facebook, you cannot force clear and re-scrape the cache, I can't actually check what LinkedIn is seeing on the page. The data shown in the link preview is clearly taken from when there were no Open Graph tags (it uses the first image in the page as the thumbnail, no description, and it uses "Home" for the title - which is not the title of the page). So either nothing is working to clear this cache, or it's ignoring my tags.

Has anyone had any luck with this working, without having to wait for the 7-day cache to clear, despite trying all of the fixes above?

Comment: I am able to update the cache by adding the parameter into the sharing url. How are you sharing your url? using customized url? (/shareArticle)

Comment: When using this in the past, it was just a case of waiting for the cache to clear, then it started working, which isn't ideal. Normally adding extra query strings has worked for me in the past but you have tried this already. Did you add the parameter like this? `/?sometext`

Comment: Did waiting for 7 days end up working?